# ToggleButton function is notchecked is not work

Tags: java, android

i have ToggleButton that do 2 function if it checked it will insert item in database mysql
if not it will delete item from mysql 
the first function is work but the second is not 
it say that

```
10-25 16:14:05.618: D/Delete student In manage(401): {"message":"No student found","success":0}
```

and i am sure about that the student is fund because i insert it before when i click check
for the ToggleButton

```
toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            // absent
                            id = student.get(holder.position)
                                    .get(TAG_StudentID);
                            new ManageAttendance().execute();

                        } else {
                            id = student.get(holder.position)
                                    .get(TAG_StudentID);
                            new DeleteInManage().execute();


                        }
                    }
                });
```

the whole code

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static String url_delete_in_manage = "http://10.0.2.2/SmsPhp/delete_in_manage.php";
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.position = position;

        holder.toggle
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            // absent
                            id = student.get(holder.position)
                                    .get(TAG_StudentID);
                            new ManageAttendance().execute();

                        } else {
                            id = student.get(holder.position)
                                    .get(TAG_StudentID);
                            new DeleteInManage().execute();


                        }
                    }
                });


        return convertView;

    }

    private static class ViewHolder {

        ToggleButton toggle;
    }

    /*****************************************************************
     * Background Async Task to Delete student

    /*****************************************************************
     * Background Async Task to Delete student
     * */
    class DeleteInManage extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            Date = mYear + "-" + mMonth + "-" + mDay;

            c1 = "77";
        Status ="A";
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StudentID", id));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Date", Date));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SectionID", c1));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Status", Status));

                // getting student details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_delete_in_manage, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Delete student In manage ", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // student successfully deleted

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }


}
```

the php code that call when it want to delete

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will delete a student from table
 * A student is identified by student id 
 */
// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['StudentID']) && isset($_POST['Date']) && isset($_POST['SectionID']) && isset($_POST['Status']))
 {
    $StudentID = $_POST['StudentID'];
      $Date = $_POST['Date'];
        $SectionID = $_POST['SectionID'];
           $Status  = $_POST['Status'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql update row with matched pid
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM attends WHERE StudentID = $StudentID && Date=$Date && SectionID=$SectionID && Status =$Status " );

    // check if row deleted or not
    if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) 
    {
        // successfully updated 
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = " student successfully deleted";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else
    {
        // no Section found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No student found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

can you help me to solve it

Comment: That's too much code.  Can you please filter it and only leave what's relevant?

Comment: @AleksG i edit you now can u see